# Intent to open the next layout crashes

Tags: android, android-intent

I've studied from another app I coded in class which uses the `Intent` to change to another class and layout and I thought the code was similar to what I have below. As it is, when I tap the 'New Game' button it simply crashes. I played around with commenting out the `.stop` and `.release` functions of my `MediaPlayer` and I did notice it kills the music before it tries to get into the `Intent` (then crashes). I'd appreciate any help, I've spent a few days trying to dig through forums :)

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mpTheme;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mpTheme=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sttngtheme);
    mpTheme.start();
    Button newGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newGameButton);
    Button loadGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadGameButton);
    Button instructionsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.instructionsButton);
    final MainActivity mainActivity = this;

    newGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mpTheme.stop();
            mpTheme.release();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You clicked New Game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent startGameIntent = new Intent(mainActivity, Game.class);
            startActivity(startGameIntent);

        }
    });

    loadGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Loading capability not yet coded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


    instructionsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Instructions not yet coded.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}//end onCreate

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mpTheme.isPlaying()){
        mpTheme.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(mpTheme.isPlaying()){
        mpTheme.stop();
        mpTheme.release();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(mpTheme.isPlaying()==false){
        mpTheme.start();
    }
}
```

}

Game.java:

```
public class Game extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quadrantspace);
}
```

}

Logcat:

```
12-10 21:09:19.978: D/AndroidRuntime(9184): Shutting down VM

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184): Process: com.ferriss.superstartrek, PID: 9184

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.ferriss.superstartrek/com.ferriss.superstartrek.Game}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1868)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1568)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3755)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3716)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4036)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3998)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at com.ferriss.superstartrek.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)

12-10 21:09:19.980: E/AndroidRuntime(9184):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

12-10 21:09:21.509: I/Process(9184): Sending signal. PID: 9184 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You should post the stacktrace from the crash log. You should also see this post on how to do some basic debugging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Thanks I'll look at that post now

Comment: It appears the 4th entry is the exception I should be looking into. The 'ActivityNotFoundException' and mentions the manifest file. Looking at manifest file and the game.java file isn't mentioned there but I was told not to mess with this file?

Comment: who told you that? All of your classes that extend `Activity` need to be declared in your manifest.

Comment: My instructor for mobile apps 1. Could have been because we were brand new to it all, in the course of mobile apps 1 thru 3 we've never touched it. I'll do that and try it. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I've done all this. It still gives me an error that the app crashes. However now it does go to the next layout lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your destination activity in the manifest file. For more info on how to add your Game.class to your Manifest check the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Declaring)

Also, you don't need to declare `mainActivity` variable separately to use inside your `newGameButton` `setOnClickListener` method. Simply you can create an Intent like this -

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
startActivity(i);
```